# How to display country using Facebook sdk 5 with php

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Facebook sdk 5 with php and i have set the parametters to retrieve the country

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location', $accessToken->getValue());
```

However when i do

```
$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo "Country: ".$me->getProperty('country')."<br>";
```

Nothing is being displayed. How to retrieve the country ?

Comment: Your request as it is now does not even return a country at all. You need to start by requesting the `location` object _inside_ `location` in your field list (`location{location}`.) And then you get the `location` property, because that is still what you get on the first level. You have to reach into that object then to fish out the properties you are interested in.

Comment: Can you please post the code so i may know how to do that and then validate your answer ? I am not too familiar with some aspect of facebook sdk even though i read it.